# Do I have to cast an Object object to a specific type before using it in my contains and equals method?

Tags: java, object, casting

So I have a Hospital class and inside it, I have a method called remove(Object object) which checks what kind of Object the parameter input is. Then after finding the instance of the object I use my equals method to find the object in the ArrayList to remove. My question is, do I have to cast the object to the specific type before using it?
Something like this: .........equals((Patient) object))?

```
public boolean remove(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof Department){
            departments.remove(object);
            return true;
        }
        if(object instanceof Patient){
            for(int i = 0; i < departments.size(); i ++){
                for(int j = 0; j < departments.size(); j ++) {
                    if (departments.get(i).getPatients().get(j).equals(object)) {
                        departments.get(i).getPatients().remove(j);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(object instanceof Employee){
            for(int i = 0; i < departments.size(); i ++){
                for(int j = 0; j < departments.size(); j ++) {
                    if (departments.get(i).getEmployees().get(j).equals(object)) {
                        departments.get(i).getEmployees().remove(j);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: A more readable solution would be to separate the 3 `if`s in 3 methods each for one object type : `removeDepartment(Department department)`, `removePatient` etc. And no, you don't have to cast it like you've said.

Comment: just make sure you have implemented .equals of the corresponding class

Comment: Yes, you should cast the object to access the object's method. but for using the equal method you don't need to do that.

Comment: but your loops are a bit strange, I mean that `j` is looping up to `departments.size()` - is `getPatients()` and `getEmployees()` returning a collection that has the same same size as `getDepartments()`? (if it is a `List` there is no need to check if the values are equals, just call `remove()` and use the returned value to know if it was removed or not) ((neither `equals` nor `remove` need casting since both accept an `Object`))

Answer (score 2):

No need to cast it. `equals(object)` and `equals((Patient) object)` resolve to the same method, if it is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Dorian Gray's answer is fine, but a recommendation for refactoring:

- implement equals and hashCode on your classes
- make departments a collection, if it is not already
- use Java's for-each loop (or streams)

So the double for-loops become

```
...
for (Department department : departments) {
  if (department.getEmployees().contains(object)) {
    department.getEmployees().remove(object);
    return true;
  }
}
...
```